# Check if a class is public or private

Tags: c#, types

As the title says, how can I determine if a particular class is public or private?

I've tried several approaches but without success and I couldn't find any answer to this question within this site.

```
using System;

namespace ReflectionPublicClass
{
    public class Program
    {
        private class Jedi
        {
            public int MidiChlorians { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type type = typeof(Jedi);
            try
            {
                Jedi obi = (Jedi)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                // If public class do something

                // If private do something else
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Use Reflection for this.

Comment: If a class is private, surely it wouldn't be accessible anyway.

Comment: Determine how? Where do you have this class? Can you show some code?

Comment: @Alex I've tried with reflection but couldn't find a way to figured out when is a public type without wrapping with a try statement. It must be another way

Comment: @CodeCaster I add some code

Comment: System.Type has a [IsPublic property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.ispublic.aspx) ...

Comment: @PaoloFalabella that sounds good but it does not work with nested classes

Comment: Is it necessary all those -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already determined the type (`typeof(Jedi)`) you are almost there. The `Type` class has two properties: `IsPublic` and `IsNonPublic`. You can use them to determine the access mode of your types:

```
public class Public
{ }
internal class Program
{
    private class Private
    {

    }
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Private pr = new Private();
        Console.WriteLine(pr.GetType().IsPublic); // false
        Public pu = new Public();
        Console.WriteLine(pu.GetType().IsPublic); // true

    }

}
```

But there are some pitfalls. As already mentioned in the comments, you will hardly be able to create an instance of a `private` class, unless it was declared inside the same class as the method that is trying to determine the access modifier.

Furthermore, these properties (`IsPublic`) determines the *effective* access to the type. So if you declare a public class inside an internal class, `IsPublic` will return `false` again:

```
internal class Program
{
    public class Public
    { }

    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Public pu = new Public();
        Console.WriteLine(pu.GetType().IsPublic); // false, because Program is internal
    }
}
```

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there may be more interesting solutions using reflection. You may want to read again the [MSDN articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) on the `Type` class.

**UPDATE**

The [TypeInfo class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.aspx) has more properties like `IsNested`, `IsNestedPublic` and `IsNestedPrivate`. You can access that via:

```
TypeInfo info = obi.GetType().GetTypeInfo();
```

I'm still not sure why you want to determine this, but maybe using these properties and the [Type.DeclaringType property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.declaringtype.aspx) you can infer the information you need.

Comment: Even being "Program" a public class, if "Jedi" is nested, IsPublic() will always return false in my example. So still no way to figured it out...

Comment: I see but without GetTypeInfo(). Example:
Type type = obi.GetType();  if (type.IsNestedPublic)